# Perform an action on JSP if redirected from a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, servlets, jsp-tags

I want to perform an action on a JSP if redirected from a specific servlet only else do nothing.Is it possible?

In my JSP there are different errors defined. This JSP calls a servlet (with contentType as application/pdf) which opens in a new tab and searches for a PDF for 25 seconds and then if PDF is not found redirects to same JSP which shows the error message "File not found". I want to show the error if called from servlet only else do nothing.

JSP Code:

```
  <%}else if(hPP!=null && hPP.get("errorcode")!=null && hPP.get("errorcode").toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Issue")){%>
                <c:if test="${cameFromServlet}">
                                    <div class="SplInputField">
                                        <label class="FontBlod">Download fail</label>
                                    </div>
                </c:if>
```

servlet code

```
    if (content == null) {
        request.setAttribute("cameFromServlet", true);
        String redirectJspUrl = request.getParameter("homeRedirect");
        String strReceiptPage =
        redirectJspUrl.substring(0, redirectJspUrl.lastIndexOf("/")) +
            "/GetQReceiptPage";
        response.sendRedirect(strReceiptPage);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an attribute to the request in the servlet like this

```
httpservletRequest.setAttribute("cameFromServlet", true)
```

then in your JSP check for it

```
<c:if test="${cameFromServlet}">
  DO STUFF HERE
</c:if>
```

**EDIT:**

What you have done in your edit will not work, since you are doing a redirect.  Which means the browser is sent a 302 response to tell it to issue another request against the new url.  Do you have a specific requirement to change the url for the user?  If so you will need to add the cameFromServlet attribute to the session instead - like this:

`req.getSession().setAttribute("cameFromServlet", true);`

Bare in mind though, that `cameFromServlet` attribute will remain on the session until you unset it so if there was another time that jsp page is shown you will run into problems unless you do something to unset it - either by introducing another servlet in the middle and moving it from the session to the request - thus simulating Springs flash map behaviour or unset it in the JSP after you have used it - like this:

```
<c:remove var="cameFromServlet" scope="session" />
```

If you do not need the URL to change for the user, you can change your servlet code to make use of a request dispatcher (what I thought you were doing)

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("/yourjsp.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(req, resp);
```

Comment: Thanks for JSTL does ( if test != )works or is there any other keyword for not?

Comment: You can use ! Or the word not there is also an exists keyword

Comment: it doesn't work in my case.Sorry for basic Q but I'm new to programming world. I have added the JSP/servlet code in the Q above

Comment: Yes @Sam ,IT helped a lot to make things clear.Thanks

Comment: Great news :). Good luck!